# MongoDB $and query is not satisfying all condition?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I am trying to query 0-6 conditions as per the user wants

[image]

my query in mongo is

```
var query = {}
    query['$and'] = [];

    if(req.body.input.inputCustomer !== "All"){
        query['$and'].push({
            salesOrderCustomerName: req.body.input.inputCustomer
        })
    }
    if(req.body.input.inputLocation !== "All"){
        query['$and'].push({
            salesOrderSubLocation: {
                "$gte": req.body.input.inputLocation
            }
        })
    }
    if(req.body.input.inputItem !== "All"){
        query['$and'].push({
            salesOrderItemList :{$elemMatch:{salesOrderSelectedItem: req.body.input.inputItem}}
        })
    }
    if(req.body.isDate === false){
        query['$and'].push({
            salesOrderDateCreated: {
                "$gte": req.body.input.inputFromDate
            }
        })

        query['$and'].push({
            salesOrderDateCreated: {
                "$lte": req.body.input.inputToDate
            }
        })
    }

    query['$and'].push({salesOrderLocation: req.query.loc})
```

but when I searched for location 1. location 2 also appeared!

[image]

Here's my database

[image]

See ID 46 to 48 they are sub location 2 but I searched for sub location 1 only and they still appear. What's wrong with my query? I used $and

Comment: You used `$gte` with location.

Comment: See above comment but in general it is advisable to post an example input shape or two and an example of the output you seek instead.